PDF created from Google Sheets in apps script is not displaying one Sheets "drawing" in MacOS Preview
I have a festival waiver pdf created by Apps Script, triggered by a form. The PDF displays properly in Acrobat Reader and Google Drive Preview but not in MacOS Preview.
The pdf is created using a spreadsheet made with Drive.Files.create() from a template. The PDF blob is created using UrlFetchApp.fetch(). The PDF itself is made with DriveApp.getFolderById().createFile().
The majority of the text is in Google Sheets, "drawings" inserted over cells to justify the text.
All the Sheets' drawings display properly in the three PDF viewers I've tried, except for one drawing of a box for initials.
It's very puzzling since almost the entire PDF is created with "Drawings." I'm not sure why only one drawing would not appear.


Since the pdf is saved to my Drive as well as emailed to the participant, I tried downloading the Drive copy and the emailed copy. Both show properly in Acrobat, but not in MacOS Preview. I tried looking at View settings in Preview, but could not find anything that would make sense.

Thanks, your comment lead me to check the drawings and the one in question was overlapping another. MacOS Preview must handle those objects differently.

I was able to solve this by deleting the drawing of the "initial" box and adding it to the drawing next to it.
I believe the boundaries of the text boxes in the two drawings were overlapping each other. Preview must have a different way of interpreting that. The PDF looks fine in both Preview and Acrobat now.
The drawing that didn't appear before was a text box inside a drawn rectangle. The text box was larger than the rectangle and it overlapped the text box of the drawing next to it.
